# Query for retrieving data records for a specific date range in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, query-builder

I have a table having `record_date` and corresponding `amount` field.I was trying to retrieve total amount grouping by the months of the date .
 I am new to laravel and in normal php i would have used the following mysql query -->
 `SELECT MONTH(record_date),YEAR(record_date),SUM(amount)`
 `FROM table_name`
 `WHERE record_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)`
 `GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date);`

This simply returns the total amount collected for last 6 months each grouped by the month and the year .
04 | 2014 | 200.00
06 | 2014 | 500.00 
08 | 2014 | 100.00 
 I have read [Laravel eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) documentation but cannot find something equivalent to the query i am trying to run . I dont know if this is right way but the nearest equivalent to the above query, i came across is

```
$data = SOME_MODEL::whereBetween('record_date', array(01, 12))->get();
```

But not sure if its even close to what i am trying to do.
Problem is the documentation does not gives date functions like now() and other which we normally always use in the mysql queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `raw` query and you may try this (Not tested but should work):

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
  ->select(DB::raw('MONTH(record_date) as m, YEAR(record_date) as y, SUM(amount) as t'))
  ->whereRaw('record_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)')
  ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(record_date), MONTH(created_at)'))
  ->get();
```

Comment: Both the answers are working perfectly but your answer is short and a little easy on eyes so i will accept it .Just out of curiosity is their really no Eloquent solution for this or for queries like this raw is the only solution ?

Comment: You may use `ModelName::select(DB::raw(...))` but I think it's better.

Comment: I answered first :-( but oh well. Eloquent is for more basic model/object relationships. Eloquent is not better or worse than Query Builder. They both have their strengths and weaknesses. You just need to choose the most appropriate one for the situation. `DB::raw` is required a lot here is because there are no local database interface methods for MySQL functions like `YEAR()`, `MONTH()`, `DATE_SUB()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubt.I thought there must be some fancy way to do this in "Laravel" but seems like using DB::raw fits best for complex queries as of now. Thanks !

Comment: I think `Jakobud` cleared the question very well, yes because you have used so many `mySql` functions so `raw` query is must @VishalNair, all the best :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using Eloquent for a more complex query such as this. Just stick with the query builder:

```
$data = DB::table('table_name')
  ->select(DB::raw('MONTH(record_date)'),DB::raw('YEAR(record_date)'),DB::raw('SUM(amount)'))
  ->where('record_date', '>', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)'))
  ->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(record_date)'))
  ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(record_date)'))
  ->get();
```

Unfortunately, since you are using so many MySQL functions, you need to add in a lot of `DB::raw` methods. But it should work. This is untested but it should be very close.

Comment: Yes it worked but WereWolf's answer is just a little more polished . Sorry bro :)