# How can I use the sentence "Order By Hour" in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to order my query by hour, but I don't know how to do it. In MySql will be:

```
ORDER BY HOUR(FechaTermino) // FechaTermino = Timestamp... (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss)
```

but in laravel??

this is my `Query Builder`

```
$servicios = DB::table('Servicio_Tecnico')
            ->join('Servicio', 'Servicio_Tecnico.Servicio_idServicio', '=', 'Servicio.idServicio')
            ->join('Tecnico', 'Servicio_Tecnico.Tecnico_idTecnico', '=', 'Tecnico.idTecnico')
            ->whereRaw('DAY(Servicio.FechaTermino) = ?', array($dia))
            ->where('Servicio.Completado', '=', '1')
            ->orderBy('FechaTermino', 'Desc')
            ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: 0 larvel experience but crazy guess is ` ->orderBy('HOUR(FechaTermino)', 'Desc')`

Comment: @Dagon I was trying but doen't work

Comment: I believe ordering by `HOUR(FechaTermino)` may have unexpected results. Keep in mind by doing that you are disconsidering the order of dates.

Comment: +1, @Dagon, really your crazy guess is very powerful, very closed tho :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a `raw` query:

```
->orderBy(DB::raw('HOUR(FechaTermino)'))
```

Check this answer, [very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24519775/query-for-retrieving-data-records-for-a-specific-date-range-in-laravel-4/24519952#24519952).

Comment: Can I add ``Desc`` to your answer?

Comment: you have my permission to do so

Comment: So kind of you @Dagon :-)